# why android:breakStrategy not working in TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I have set the `breakStrategy` to `simple` and the textview is not behaving properly. This is the result I am getting:

[image]

This is the code I used:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_list_item_notes"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/row_top_padding_12"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            android:breakStrategy="simple"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textDirection="locale"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/amount_and_action_barrier"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_list_item_contact_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_list_item_date"
            tools:targetApi="m" />
```

I want the text to be displayed in such a way that **the first line should fill the whole width of the textview**. I mean the word **break** should start in the first line itself. Doesn't matter if it breaks and splits between both lines.
I am testing on device with API level 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to replace spaces in your text with [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). In my project I have kotlin extension function for this:

```
fun String?.useNonBreakingSpace() = this.orEmpty()
    .replace(
        Constants.REGULAR_SPACE_CHARACTER,
        Constants.NON_BREAKABLE_SPACE_UNICODE
    )
```

and

```
object Constants {

    ...

    const val REGULAR_SPACE_CHARACTER = ' '
    const val REGULAR_SPACE = REGULAR_SPACE_CHARACTER.toString()
    const val NON_BREAKABLE_SPACE_HTML = "&#160;"
    const val NON_BREAKABLE_SPACE_UNICODE = '\u00A0'

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. Whe i use ur code, this text is not coming as a non-breaking space in my textview. Its coming like this `This&#160;is&#160;a&#160;dummy&#160;text&#160;to&#160;demo&#160;the&#160;break&#160;strategy`

Comment: Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot that I'm using html characters in my use case - when I'm setting text to my TextView with this funcion I am using HtmlCompat like this: myTextView.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml("my text".useNonBreakingSpace(), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT). But be aware that it will parse the HTML tags also (eg. <strong>). The other option (I think better in this situation) is to replace space character with unicode non-breaking space using .replace(' ', '\u00A0'). I will edit my answer in a moment.