# Android Jetpack Compose: How to make Text utilize complete row space and break the word to new line in case of overflow?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I would like the text to utilize complete row space and break to a new line if the word overflows the row space. Is there any way to achieve this in Jetpack Compose Text? I did not find any solution here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text

Expected:

[image]

Current:
[image]

Code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
            setContent {
                MaterialTheme {
                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                    ) {
                        ShowText()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun ShowText() {
        Text(text = "This is a veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrryyyyyyyyyyyy looooooong text", softWrap = true)
    }
    
    @Preview
    @Composable
    fun Preview() {
        MaterialTheme {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
                ShowText()
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution is to replace space by non breakable space :

```
@Composable
fun TestLongWord() {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .systemBarsPadding()) {
        Text(
            text = "This is a veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy looooooong text".useNonBreakingSpace()
        )
    }
}

fun String?.useNonBreakingSpace() = this.orEmpty()
    .replace(
        Constants.REGULAR_SPACE_CHARACTER,
        Constants.NON_BREAKABLE_SPACE_UNICODE
    )

object Constants {
    const val REGULAR_SPACE_CHARACTER = ' '
    const val NON_BREAKABLE_SPACE_UNICODE = '\u00A0'
}
```

The result is :

[image: Result]

Source [here](https://www.androidbugfix.com/2022/02/why-androidbreakstrategy-not-working-in.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70665236/9636037)

Comment: Although it is a working solution to use the whole row space, but sometimes words are broken among multiple lines not in a nice way. For example, "done" is split like "d" and "one" one letter on the first line, other three on the second

Answer (score 0):

As of Compose 1.4, released in March 2023, we now have more agency over line-breaking behavior by using [`TextStyle.lineBreak`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle#lineBreak()). From the [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/03/whats-new-in-jetpack-compose-march-23-release.html):

> Configure line-breaking behavior using [`TextStyle.lineBreak`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle#lineBreak()). Use built-in semantic configurations like [`Heading`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/LineBreak#Heading()), [`Paragraph`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/LineBreak#Paragraph()), or [`Simple`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/LineBreak#Simple()), or construct your own `LineBreak` configuration with the desired [`Strategy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/LineBreak.Strategy), [`Strictness`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/LineBreak.Strictness), and [`WordBreak`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/LineBreak.WordBreak) values.

To achieve the result originally desired by this question, we can use the `Heading` configuration, as demonstrated below:

[image]

Code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ShowText(
    text: String = "This is a veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrryyyyyyyyyyyy looooooong text",
    textStyle: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
) {
    Column {
        Text("Simple")
        Text(
            text = text,
            style = textStyle.copy(
                lineBreak = Simple
            )
        )
        Divider()
        Text("Heading")
        Text(
            text = text,
            style = textStyle.copy(
                lineBreak = Heading
            )
        )
        Divider()
        Text("Paragraph")
        Text(
            text = text,
            style = textStyle.copy(
                lineBreak = Paragraph
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: how to set like css word-break: break-all; ?